# Nginx - Even after adding the directive 'access control allow origin' the request logs error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

I am trying to run nginx infront of my nodejs application (I am using windows machine)

My NodeJS Application is running in 3000 port

I have started the Nginx at 8070 port

When i try to hit http://localhost:8070/ from browser am getting the issue quoted below

This is my Nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen       8070;
    server_name  localhost;

location / {
    access_log   logs/access.log;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type,Accept';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_pass http://my-app/;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 240s;
    }
    }
```

But still i am getting the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/my-app/api/engineOptions/get. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8070' is therefore not allowed access.

Am i missing anything in the nginx configuration regarding Access-Control-Allow-Origin directive?

Comment: The port 3000 server needs to be configured to send the Access-Control-Allow-\* response headers. The message cited in the question indicates that’s the server the request is being sent to—the one whose response lacks the headers—and that the port 8070 server is where the request is being sent *from*. So it doesn’t matter what Access-Control-Allow-\* headers you have configured on the port 8070 server—whatever changes you make there isn’t going to have any effect. You need to change the port 3000 config.

Comment: Yes, The header should be present on the resource, instead of the requester.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker So should i add another server config in the nginx for port 300 to enable access-control-allow-origin for 3000 port?

Comment: yes, you should